# How do I not violate this primary key when syncing with Azure?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, microsoft-sync-framework

### Project summary

We're creating a 'digital' kitchen where it's possible to add which items are in your fridge, freezer etc. Then it's possible to view these items on a webapplication, so you know groceries you have in your kitchen on the go.

### The database

In total there are three tables.

**Lists**

This holds ListIDs and names of these Lists, like 'Fridge' or 'Freezer'. So, this is basically the 'container'.

**Items**

Then there's *Items* which holds itemtypes, i.e. Milk, 1 gallon.

**ListItems**

Then there's *ListItems* (sorry for a slightly confusing name) which holds **specific** items. While *Items* is just a table of items which can be added, *ListItems* are the **added** items. So the rows added to this table naturally have a foreign key to both a *List* on the *Lists* table and a foreign key to an *Item* on the *Items* table. This table's primary key is a superkey, made from nearly all its attributes.

Two ListItems can refer to the same *Item* and same *List*, as long as they have different attributes. They could expire on different dates or be different unit sizes. The only thing that makes an *Item* unique is the name, like if you added a 'Ham', it would never overwrite a 'Milk'. Adding another 'Milk' would then be seen as the same *Item*

### The Problem

Here's an example. You want to add two seperate items. The first is 3 hams, each 200 g which expire on the 28th of May.
The next is another ham, this one single, but 500g and expires on the 31st of May: 
[image]

ListID 1 refers to the *List* which is called Fridge.
ItemID 1 refers to the item which is called *Ham*.

See the problem? The foreign keys are the same.

It stores just fine on our local database but when syncing with an Azure database, we get the following error:

```
{"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__#A4D1762__44A4C03D49E5E4B8'. 
Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.@changeTable'. 
The duplicate key value is (1, 1).\r\n
The data for table-valued parameter \"@changeTable\" doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter. 
SQL Server error is: 3602, state: 30\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

Is this poor database design or an Azure problem?

### Update 1

Here's how the DDL looks on the local database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ListItems] (
    [ListId] INT NOT NULL,
    [ItemId] INT NOT NULL,
    [Amount] INT NOT NULL, 
    [Volume] INT NOT NULL, 
    [Unit] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
    [ShelfLife] DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [pk_ListItems] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ShelfLife], [Volume], [Amount], [ItemId], [ListId]),
    CONSTRAINT [fk_ListItems] FOREIGN KEY ([ListId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Lists] ([ListId]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [fk_ListItems2] FOREIGN KEY ([ItemId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Items] ([ItemId]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

And the Azure database DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ListItems] (
    [ListId]    INT            NOT NULL,
    [ItemId]    INT            NOT NULL,
    [Amount]    INT            NOT NULL,
    [Volume]    INT            NOT NULL,
    [Unit]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [ShelfLife] DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ListItems] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ListId] ASC, [ItemId] ASC, [Amount] ASC, [Volume] ASC, [ShelfLife] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ListItems_dbo.Items_ItemId] FOREIGN KEY ([ItemId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Items] ([ItemId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ListItems_dbo.Lists_ListId] FOREIGN KEY ([ListId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Lists] ([ListId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

The PK CONSTRAINT line is slightly different, but the attributes are the same. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Seems to me like your primary key is not set correctly on the Azure system. as the error message states, the duplicate key value is (1,1), but your primary key need to also contain the amount, volume, unit etc`.

Comment: You mention it `stores just fine on your local database`, but then you won't have the same primary key constraints as on the Azure db because otherwise it would be failing too. Could you share some DDL code, both of the local and of the Azure db?

Comment: Maybe you should consider to add some identity column into ListItems table and make that a primary key? Your current 'superkey' could just be an unique index (to avoid duplicates) then.

Comment: Is the problem occurring when syncing between the two?the traditional approach is to use guids here, so that the key can be generated in either database and be guaranteed to be unique across the system.

Comment: I've added the DDL code for both ListItem tables!

Comment: I thought the sync framework assume the tables have the same primary key columns.  Natural keys are ok from a sync perspective.

Comment: You need remove the primary key on listed items(listed, itemid) to allow multiple entries with same itemid and listed. A new listedid might needed for the table as a primary key.

Comment: have you modified your table structure after you've provisioned in Sync Framework?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the error is where you think it is.  If the PK on the local and Azure ListItems both name the same columns (irrespective of order), they are the same.  The error message, however, mentions a different PK definition (and a different tablename):

> `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__#A4D1762__44A4C03D49E5E4B8'. 
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.@changeTable'. 
>   The duplicate key value is (1, 1).`

There appears to be a table whose name is "@changetable" -- which looks like a store procedure parameter to me -- that is defined with a two-column primary key.  Track it down and you'll solve the problem.